# How to prevent changing variable's value inside click and fadeOut function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <label class="add-genre-filter not-selected">Add genre filter</label>
    <select class="filter" name="filter[]">
        <option value="some-value">Some Item</option>
        <option value="some-value">Some Item</option>
        <option value="some-value">Some Item</option>
        <option value="some-value">Some Item</option>
    </select>
    <span class="cancel"> x </span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var genreLimit = 3;

    $('.dropdown .add-genre-filter').live( 'click', function(){
        genreLimit ? ( $(this).parent().append(options) , genreLimit-- ) : false;
        console.log(genreLimit);
    });
    $('.dropdown .cancel').live( 'click', function(){
        $(this).prev().fadeOut("normal", function(){ $(this).remove(); });
        $(this).fadeOut("normal", function(){ genreLimit++; $(this).remove(); });
        console.log(genreLimit);
    });

});
```

*NB: I'm using jQuery 1.6 that's why still using the `live()` function*

By clicking on `<span class="cancel">` both `select` and `span` fade outs and removed from the document. At the same time it increases the value of **`genreLimit`** by `1`

But If I repeatedly click the **x** in `span` then **`genreLimit`** value increases by the number of clicks until it fade outs completely. I know it should be decreased like that because it's inside the click event.

However, I want to increase the value only once in a fadeOut. So that, clicking multiple times will not change my functionality. What can be done here?

Comment: Your `.add-genre-filter` click can simply be : `if(genreLimit && !$('.dropdown .cancel').is(':animated')) $(this).parent().append(options) , genreLimit--;`

Comment: You really should look into a more modern jQuery and the .one() variation on .on(); see: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a flag to say that it is performing a fading..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var genreLimit = 3;
    var is_fading = false;

    $('.dropdown .add-genre-filter').live( 'click', function(){
        genreLimit ? ( $(this).parent().append(options) , genreLimit-- ) : false;
        console.log(genreLimit);
    });
    $('.dropdown .cancel').live( 'click', function(){
        if (is_fading) return; // don't run if it is already fading...

        is_fading = true;
        // choose the correct callback to 'unlock' the flag..
        $(this).prev().fadeOut("normal", function(){ $(this).remove(); is_fading = false;? });
        $(this).fadeOut("normal", function(){ genreLimit++; $(this).remove(); is_fading = false;? });
        console.log(genreLimit);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. What's the point of `?` at the end btw?

Comment: sorry about that...nothing, it more like "maybe here or here".